# Routing not working in my code for '/about', while home page working

Tags: reactjs, routes

Routing is not working in my code showing error `Cannot GET /about`, my code is below :

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Components/Home";
import About from "./Components/About";

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: either add exact to your first route i.e, <Route path="/" exact component={Home} /> or change the order of your routes inside <Switch /> i.e, make "{About}" as first and "{Home}" second. Because path="/" works as prefix to any route and every route starts with "/". <Switch /> works in a way that, it won't let you reach the path="/about" in case of about page, as path="/" will be satisfied in every situation & as soon as first route inside <Switch /> gets satisfied it exits without rendering other routes afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

define exact to your route-                   `<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />`

```
             <Router>
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                  <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
```

complete code

```
const App = () => (
  <Router>
      <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      </Switch>
  </Router>
)
const Home = ()=>(<div>
<h3>Home</h3>
<Link to="/about">Visit to about page</Link>
</div>)
const About = ()=><h3>About</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

how about using reach/router ?
developed by same author ryan florence

it solves this exact path problems with better route match algorithm and ease of use.

working example for the same.
https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-chebyshev-gkw31